# Why isn't my texture repeating correctly?

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to apply a brick texture to my wall using THREE.RepeatWrapping, but for some reason it is not repeating correctly. I'm using a big cube as a wall, and I've made the texture only appear on the inside of the cube with the help of THREE.BackSide.

```
var wallGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 100, 200);
texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("textures/bricks.jpg");
texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.x = 170 / 100;
texture.repeat.y = 170 / 100;

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
material.map = texture;
var wall = new THREE.Mesh(wallGeometry, material);

wall.material.side = THREE.BackSide;

scene.add(wall);
```

The result can be seen below.

[image: the result]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: as you can see at https://jsfiddle.net/567xyxo4/ your code should be working.

Comment: thanks, the texture might not be right for it

Comment: usually the texture is not the problem

Comment: I'm now using another texture and with that one it is working fine for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your texture a power of 2 in each dimension? WebGL can not repeat non-power of 2 textures. So for example a 640x480 texture will not repeat because both 640 and 480 are not powers of 2. A 1024x768 will not repeat either because while 1024 is a power of 2, 768 is not. A 512x256 texture will repeat because both dimensions are powers of 2.